# Threejs webvr with two separate renderers

Tags: three.js, webgl, webvr

I have two separate renderers with separate scenes. In one scene, I have a very expensive dynamic shader which I am rendering at a low resolution to boost fps (using .setPixelRatio(0.3). The other renderer takes care of everything else. I can render both at the same time, one on top of the other, without issue.

The problem is I cannot figure out how to render both at the same time with WebVR enabled.

Here is the relevant code

```
self.shaderRenderer.vr.enabled = true;
self.renderer.vr.enabled = true;
WEBVR.getVRDisplay( function ( display ) {
    self.renderer.vr.setDevice( display );
    self.shaderRenderer.vr.setDevice( display );
    document.body.appendChild( WEBVR.getButton( display, self.renderer.domElement ) );
});

self.shaderRenderer.animate(self.renderShader);
self.renderer.animate(self.render);
```

I can switch between the two in VR mode by swapping the renderer.domElement in the 6th line. How do I render both, one on top of the other with WebVR enabled?

Comment: any luck with this?  interesting problem.

Comment: @ox I had a little luck rendering the shader to a rendertexture at a low resolution (simulating setPixelRatio) but I was having rotational issues getting the plane aligned to the camera. I'm pretty sure I can get it working with that method but I don't have time to work on it right now unfortunately.

Comment: I have a similar situation, but I´m trying the solution at the render function. The idea is to lower the resolution, render the secondary (low-quality) background scene, then restore the resolution and render the main scene. Everything without cleaning the scene or we lost what was render from the first scene. The problem is, if I lower the resolution the first scene doesn´t show at all..    

renderer.setPixelRatio(0.25);  
renderer.render(scene2, camera);  
renderer.autoClear = false;  
  
renderer.setPixelRatio(1);  
renderer.render(scene, camera);  
renderer.autoClear = true;